# Facebook authentication not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

In my facebook app under site url I have put - http://www.mydomainname.com/users/auth/facebook/callback

I have put all the facebook credentials properly in config/initalizers/devise.rb too

The user needs to click on an image at http://www.mydomain.com/profile which points to http://www.mydomainname.com/users/auth/facebook but nothing is happening, it looks the page is redirecting and then it just shows =">http://www.mydomain.com/profile#*=*

I checked my production.log file and it is showing (I have removed part of the token for security purpose)

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 108.107.140.124 at 2013-06-02 14:15:19 +0000


Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=KJHKJHJKHKHJyadhanIUGYagdnianduifayuidfnyYYKghwViqVXpe6a69be8d50d51f9e971a06" for 108.107.140.124 at 2013-06-02 14:15:21 +0000
Processing by AuthenticationsController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQCJZPxjvAPbsHxcueSRKfK5xWQWlhxofFUBblb0fyyHgulTcPmZEVn5TzVhAbDBK1e4SPE21uIVTOj9nJ7r6lJMYYKghwViqVXpltdtEylL-v1V-EH9X9wUDLrVS3igX-al3L98MiYgW6YdPJhENBXRt3iksbmSXo33NHot8LMC8ntI9P8V0jybVXF9RZrfXetRoPrDzYsYt1mPfHB-y11evq_RKejvecHJFM81vH070uzBtS2kdjZcQNgwCdnd5CKKUHLyS22W1TAnY_m_BYjWYm59a1QfLyU2IFzeSUP0fjIp3RquzGFjAqBVpAo9MH8", "state"=>"87302acdf98eaf5ef54230526e6a69be8d50d51f9e971a06"}
**Redirected to http://www.mydomainname.com/profile**
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

**Everything looks fine still there is no authentication, what am I doing wrong ?**

EDIT - Authentication_controller.rb file has

```
  def facebook
    omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    token = omni['credentials'].token
    token_secret = omni['credentials'].secret

    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])
    if authentication
      authentication.update_attributes(:token => token, :token_secret => token_secret)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], :uid => omni['uid'], :token => token, :token_secret => token_secret)
    end 

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully connected with facebook"
    redirect_to profiles_path
  end
```

Comment: can you post your code for AuthenticationsController#facebook ?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - Jesse, I have put the Authentication controller code too

Comment: looks like you already need to be logged in before this will create an 'authentication' for you. Are you already logged in?

Comment: hi @Cyborg, are you using devise for user authentication ?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - yes, I am already logged in both the site as well as on facebook

Comment: @VSiingh - yes I am using devise for user authentication

Comment: hi @iCyborg, I have attached code in gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5699944. If you find it useful , then i can guide you how to use in you application. Please let me know.